# How to write a SOAPVAR payload in PHP for the following Soap envelope

Tags: php, xml, soap, soap-client

I'm trying to put together the PHP objects for the following SOAP envelope, PHP isn't my strongest language so struggling a bit with the nested credentials part:

**Payload Example:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:hyp="http://www.globalprocessing.ae/HyperionWeb">   
<soapenv:Header>      
   <hyp:AuthSoapHeader>                  
         <hyp:strUserName></hyp:strUserName>
         <hyp:strPassword>/hyp:strPassword>
      </hyp:AuthSoapHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <hyp:Ws_AddUpDelCredentials>
         <hyp:WSID></hyp:WSID>
         <hyp:IssCode></hyp:IssCode>
         <hyp:PublicToken></hyp:PublicToken>
         <hyp:Action></hyp:Action>
         <hyp:Credentials>
            <hyp:Credential>
               <hyp:ID></hyp:ID>
               <hyp:Type></hyp:Type>
               <hyp:Value></hyp:Value>
               <KBA_Answer></hyp:KBA_Answer>
               <KBA_AnswerOldValue></hyp:KBA_AnswerOldValue>
            </hyp:Credential>         
         </hyp:Credentials> 
      </hyp:Ws_AddUpDelCredentials>   
</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

**The Class structure I have is:**

```
class Ws_AddUpDelCredentialsRequest {

  public $paramData;
        
  public function __construct($ns, $instCode, $cardToken, $action, $credentials) {
      $this->paramData[] = new SoapVar(date('jnmhis') . rand(1000, 9999), null, null, null, 'WSID', $ns);
      $this->paramData[] = new SoapVar(substr($instCode, 0, 3), null, null, null, 'IssCode', $ns);
      $this->paramData[] = new SoapVar($cardToken, null, null, null, 'PublicToken', $ns);
      $this->paramData[] = new SoapVar($action, null, null, null, 'Action', $ns);
      $this->paramData[] = new SoapVar($credentials, null, null, null, 'Credentials', $ns);
  }
}
        
class Ws_Credential {
        
  public $paramData;
            
  public function __construct($ns, $id, $type, $value) {
      $this->paramData[] = new SoapVar($id, null, null, null, 'ID', $ns);
      $this->paramData[] = new SoapVar($type, null, null, null, 'Type', $ns);
      $this->paramData[] = new SoapVar($value, null, null, null, 'Value', $ns);
  }
}
```

**And the calling code (Minus the constructor values obvisouly):**

```
$addUpDelCredentialsResponse = $soapClient->__soapCall(
                 'Ws_AddUpDelCredentials',
                 $addUpDelCredentialsRequest->paramData,
                 array("soapaction" => 'http://www.globalprocessing.ae/HyperionWeb' . "/Ws_AddUpDelCredentials"));
```

But the endpoint is refusing it due to "No Credentials Found" which leads me to believe I'm not doing the collection correctly in the class structure.

See above for examples of what I have done so far, I played with the request objects quite a bit so there is something I'm missing.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: do you have any wsdl doc for the webservice? if you have please check you're sending in the correct format

Comment: Also you can use __getLastRequest() method to log or print the last sent request.

Comment: The example above is from the end service so i know what the format should be I just don't know how to structure my PHP code as its not my primary language!

Comment: I have got a request but it looks ok, but thought if someone with better PHP knowledge than me structured the code i could easily give that a try

Comment: Why there are two <hyp:Credentials> <hyp:Credential> in the request body? is it the expected structure?

Comment: Its a collection and then an item